# SQL: Deadlock because DELETE from child table needs XLOCK on foreign key parent table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in a foreign key relationship, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a 
(
     id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE table_b 
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    a_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES table_a(id),
    other_id int NOT NULL,
    info varchar(max) NOT NULL
)
```

`table_b` has an index on `a_id` and `other_id`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX table_b_i1 
ON table_b (a_id ASC, other_id ASC)
```

Two threads run a transaction with 3 steps:

1. Create a temporary `#table_b` to hold some new values for `table_b`
2. Delete from `table_b` where `a_id` matches a value from `#table_b` but `other_id` does not
3. Merge into `table_b` where `a_id` and `other_id` both match a value from `#table_b`

The transaction:

```sql
-- step 1
SELECT /* some stuff */ INTO #table_b

-- step 2
DELETE FROM table_b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #table_b tb_t WHERE tb_t.a_id = table_b.a_id) AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #table_b tb_t WHERE tb_t.a_id = table_b.a_id AND tb_t.other_id = table_b.other_id)

-- step 3
MERGE INTO table_b AS target USING #table_b AS source
ON target.a_id = source.a_id AND target.other_id = source.other_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
  target.info = source.info
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN
INSERT (a_id, other_id, info)
VALUES (source.a_id, source.other_id, source.info)
```

The deadlock is happening when one thread is running step 2 and another is running step 3. It's very important to note that **at no point ever** is one thread using the same `a_id` as the other; that is, the temporary `#table_b` in one thread will never match a single `a_id` in the `#table_b` from another thread, ever, period. Here's what the deadlock graph looks like:

```xml
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process_step2" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process_step2" ...>
      <executionStack>
        ...
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
/* STEP 2 */
      </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process_step3" ...>
      <executionStack>
        ...
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
/* STEP 3 */
      </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <pagelock ... subresource="FULL" objectname="table_b" ... mode="U" associatedObjectId==>(table_b.id)>
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process_step3" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process_step2" mode="IU" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock ... subresource="FULL" objectname="table_a" ... mode="IX" associatedObjectId==>(table_b_i1)>
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process_step2" mode="IX" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process_step3" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

The first pagelock makes total sense--the merge (step 3) is updating a lot of rows in table_b so it has a U pagelock, and the delete (step 2) is deleting individual rows from table_b, so it's trying to get an IU pagelock.

The second makes no sense to me at all: sure, the merge (step 3) should be trying to read the index, which includes `a_id`, to satisfy the foreign key constraint on `table_a.id`; but why is the delete (step 2) looking at `table_a` at all? I could understand why an insert or an update would need to make sure that same constraint was satisfied, but why a delete? At no time does step 2 reference `table_a`, and especially not `table_a.id`.

I can't understand why this transaction is causing deadlock and especially not why the deletion in the child table of a foreign key constraint should require a lock on the parent table. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this could help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158264/sql-locks-parent-table-while-deleting-child-table-row

Comment: upvote for nice explanation and all details

Comment: @Jens I saw that, but the accepted answer is just to create an index on the parent id column, which I already have in the `table_b_i1` index

Comment: @mavirick could you check if an index on just a_id changes your execution plan? Depending on your data the index on both columns might not be limiting enough.

Comment: @Jens it looks like that may have done it, although I'm having a hard time understanding why. I actually originally adjusted the original index--which was just on `a_id`--to be on both `a_id` and `other_id` in an attempt to fix the problem. Why would having both indexes be necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Try to supply step 2: DELETE FROM table_b **with(tablock)** ......

then no other process will run step 2 untill you finish step 3 and commit.

If your process runs without transaction then you should use "**with(tablock)**" in both statements or add "begin tran" and "commit"